# Teria como adicionar um parâmetro em: system("color", var) na linguagem C?

Tags: c, c++

Estou criando um programinha simples, pra mudar a cor do sistema. 
Só que, quero dar a opção para o usuário escrever a cor que ele quer.
Ex: Tem a tabela
1: Azul
2: Verde
F: Vermelho
C: Amarelo

Sendo F cor de fundo e 1 cor da fonte. 
Então olhando a tabela, ele escolheria as cores, e eu armazenaria
sua escolha em uma variável opccor.
Com isso, eu tentei fazer dessa forma, mas não deu certo.
Alguém tem alguma ideia de como posso fazer ?
Obg pela atenção.

/* system("color F1", opccor);*/
.
system("color %c", opccor);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `system()` não recebe parâmetros, mas você pode usar a `snprintf()` para compor a sua *string* de comando:

```
char buf[20];
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "color %s", opccor);
system(buf);
```