# Erro ao criar filho - Escalonamento de processos usando fork

Tags: c, c++, processo

Escreva um programa em C/C++ denominado novela.cpp que faça o seguinte:

O processo Pai cria um processo Filho1 em 10 segundos e um processo Filho2 em

20 segundos e depois fica executando indefinidamente. Pois bem, desenvolvi o codigo, ele cria o pai, cria o filho 1, porem na criaçao do segundo filho, ele nao atende a condiçao e nao cria. Alguem me da uma ajuda.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
//printf("--beginning of program\n");
int segundosPai=0;
int segundosFilho1=0;
int segundosFilho2=0;
int segundosNeto1=0;
int segundosNeto2 = 0;
bool pai, filho1, filho2, neto1, neto2;
pid_t pid = fork();
int pidPai, pidFilho1, pidFilho2, pidNeto1, pidNeto2;

while(true){
    segundosPai++;
    if (pid == 0)
    {   
        if(segundosPai >= 10){
            pidFilho1 = getpid();// processo filho 1
            filho1 = true;
            while(filho1 == true){
                segundosFilho1++;
                cout<<"Sou o FILHO 1, tenho "<<segundosFilho1<<" anos e o PID: "<<pidFilho1<<" e o PID do meu pai e: "<<getppid()<<"\n";
                sleep(1);
                //criacao do filho 2
                if(segundosPai >= 20){//ELE NAO ATENDE ESSA CONDIÇÃO
                    pidFilho2 = getpid();//processo filho 2
                    filho2 == true;
                    while(filho2 == true){
                        segundosFilho2++;
                        cout<<"Sou o FILHO 2, tenho "<<segundosFilho2<<" anos e o PID: "<<pidFilho2<<" e o PID do meu pai e: "<<getppid()<<"\n";
                        sleep(1);
                    }//fim while filho 2
                }
            }//fim while filho 1

        }           
    }
    else if (pid > 0)
    {   
        pidPai = getpid();
        pai = true;
        // processo pai
        cout<<"Sou o PAI, tenho "<<segundosPai<<" anos e o PID: "<<pidFilho1<<"\n";

    }
    else
    {
        // fork failed
        printf("Falha ao criar o fork!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    sleep(1);
}//fim do laço while

printf("--Fim do programa--\n");

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lógica que você está usando está errada; para facilitar, vamos quebrar o código em múltiplas funções usando a descrição informal que você fez:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

void
proc_filho(const char * nome) {
    int num_segundos = 0;
    while (true) {
        sleep(1);
        num_segundos ++;
        cout << "Sou o processo " << nome << " (PID " << getpid() << "), estou rodando há " << num_segundos << " segundos." << endl;
    }
}

int
main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    int num_segundos = 0;

    while (true) {
        sleep(1);
        num_segundos ++;
        cout << "Sou o processo pai (PID " << getpid() << "), estou rodando há " << num_segundos << " segundos." << endl;
        // aos 10 segundos, gera o filho 1.
        if (num_segundos == 10 && ! fork()) proc_filho("filho 1");
        // aos 20 segundos, gera o filho 2.
        if (num_segundos == 20 && ! fork()) proc_filho("filho 2");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

O processo pai nasce na `main)()`, dorme um segundo, imprime sua identificação, e testa se chegou ao ponto de dez segundos, depois testa se chegou ao ponto de vinte segundos. Em ambos os `if`s, como o operador `&&` tem a característica de *shortcut evaluation*, o segundo operando (`! fork()`) não é executado até que o primeiro (`num_segundos == 10`/`num_segundos == 20`) seja verdadeiro. Assim ele vai repetindo.

Quando `num_segundos` chega a dez, o primeiro operando retorna verdadeiro e então ele roda o `fork()`, criando o primeiro filho. No caso do processo pai, ele vai receber o pid do processo filho (que é maior que zero), que negado retorna 0 (isto é, falso). Então ele não entra no *then*. Dez segundos depois, `num_segundos` chega a vinte, o primeiro operando do segundo if retorna verdadeiro, e o segundo `fork()` é avaliado. Novamente, um valor maior que zero é retornado, que negado vira zero, então o *then* é pulado.

Depois disso, o pai só dorme um segundo, incrementa o `num_segundos`, e reporta o seu estado eternamente.

No caso dos filhos 1 e 2, eles são criados no `fork()`, que retorna zero para eles. Negado, vira um, então eles entram nos respectivos *then*, que invocam a função `proc_filho()`. Esta função recebe o nome do processo (para propósito de reportar o estado), e não retorna. Assim, garantimos que o pai vai sempre rodar no `main()`, e os filhos na `proc_filho()`, evitando termos que testar se é o pai ou o filho rodando.

Os filhos têm seu próprio contador (o `num_segundos` local à `proc_filho()`), e reportam o seu próprio estado normalmente. Não têm acesso à contagem do pai, embora pudessem receber do pai a quantidade de segundos em que foram criados para simular a contagem do pai através de uma soma simples.

Note que, neste caso, chamamos `getpid()` todas as iterações para conseguir o nosso próprio pid; poderíamos chamar uma só vez, antes do *loop*, e guardar o número numa variável local, se você achar melhor. Mas como `getpid()` é uma *system call* simples e rápida, não vejo muita necessidade.

EDIT: Duas fases novas: Primeiro, cada um dos filhos cria um neto (chamados neto 1 e neto 2) depois de 15 segundos.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

void
proc_neto(const char * nome) {
    int num_segundos = 0;
    while (true) {
        sleep(1);
        num_segundos ++;
        cout << "Sou o processo " << nome << " (PID " << getpid() << "), estou rodando há " << num_segundos << " segundos." << endl;
    }
}

void
proc_filho(const char * nome) {
    int num_segundos = 0;
    char nome_filho[7] = "neto x";

    // o dígito fica na 8ª posição do nome do filho, repete na 6ª do neto
    nome_filho[5] = nome[7];
    while (true) {
        sleep(1);
        num_segundos ++;
        cout << "Sou o processo " << nome << " (PID " << getpid() << "), estou rodando há " << num_segundos << " segundos." << endl;
        if (num_segundos == 15 && ! fork()) proc_neto(nome_filho);
    }
}

int
main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    int num_segundos = 0;

    while (true) {
        sleep(1);
        num_segundos ++;
        cout << "Sou o processo pai (PID " << getpid() << "), estou rodando há " << num_segundos << " segundos." << endl;
        // aos 10 segundos, gera o filho 1.
        if (num_segundos == 10 && ! fork()) proc_filho("filho 1");
        // aos 20 segundos, gera o filho 2.
        if (num_segundos == 20 && ! fork()) proc_filho("filho 2");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Terceira e última fase: No instante 50 segundos, Filho1 mata Pai. - No instante 55 segundos, Filho1 mata seu filho e se suicida dois segundos depois disto. - No instante 60 segundos, Neto2 mata seu pai e se suicida três segundos depois, terminando com a saga da família.

Aqui é melhor separar as procs dos dois filhos e dos dois netos, já que os comportamentos deles passam a diferir. Poderíamos também guardar essas diferenças em algum tipo de estrutura de dados, mas não vale a pena aqui. Vamos assumir que esses instantes se referem ao relógio do pai:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

void
proc_neto1(int dtnasc) {
    int num_segundos = 0;
    while (true) {
        sleep(1);
        num_segundos ++;
        cout << "Sou o processo neto 1 (PID " << getpid() << "), estou rodando há " << num_segundos << " segundos." << endl;
    }
}

void
proc_neto2(int dtnasc) {
    int num_segundos = 0;
    while (true) {
        sleep(1);
        num_segundos ++;
        cout << "Sou o processo neto 2 (PID " << getpid() << "), estou rodando há " << num_segundos << " segundos." << endl;
        if (dtnasc + num_segundos == 60) {
            cout << "Neto 2 ficou louco! Matou seu pai (PID " << getppid() << ")" << endl;
            kill(getppid(), SIGKILL);
        }
        if (dtnasc + num_segundos == 63) {
            cout << "Não aguentando a pressão, neto 2 se suicida." << endl;
            kill(getppid(), SIGKILL);
        }
    }
}

void
proc_filho1(int dtnasc) {
    int num_segundos = 0;
    int pid_filho = 0;

    while (true) {
        sleep(1);
        num_segundos ++;
        cout << "Sou o processo filho 1 (PID " << getpid() << "), estou rodando há " << num_segundos << " segundos." << endl;
        if (num_segundos == 15 && ! (pid_filho = fork())) proc_neto1(dtnasc + num_segundos);
        if (dtnasc + num_segundos == 50) {
            cout << "Filho 1 ficou louco! Matou seu pai (PID = " << getppid() << ")" << endl;
            kill(getppid(), SIGKILL);
        }
        if (dtnasc + num_segundos == 55) {
            cout << "Filho 1 continua louco! Matou seu filho (PID " << pid_filho << ")" << endl;
            kill(pid_filho, SIGKILL);
        }
        if (dtnasc + num_segundos == 57) {
            cout << "Não aguentando a pressão, filho 1 se suicida." << endl;
            kill(getpid(), SIGKILL);
        }
    }
}

void
proc_filho2(const char * nome) {
    int num_segundos = 0;

    while (true) {
        sleep(1);
        num_segundos ++;
        cout << "Sou o processo " << nome << " (PID " << getpid() << "), estou rodando há " << num_segundos << " segundos." << endl;
        if (num_segundos == 15 && ! fork()) proc_neto2(dtnasc + num_segundos);
    }
}

int
main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    int num_segundos = 0;

    while (true) {
        sleep(1);
        num_segundos ++;
        cout << "Sou o processo pai (PID " << getpid() << "), estou rodando há " << num_segundos << " segundos." << endl;
        // aos 10 segundos, gera o filho 1.
        if (num_segundos == 10 && ! fork()) proc_filho1(num_segundos);
        // aos 20 segundos, gera o filho 2.
        if (num_segundos == 20 && ! fork()) proc_filho2(num_segundos);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Como você pode ver, ao separar as funcionalidades distintas em funções distintas, fica mais fácil estender o comportamento do programa. Nesta última fase, por exemplo, cada processo rodava uma proc diferente um do outro, então não precisava mais passar o nome do filho; por outro lado, passei a passar a "data de nascimento" para poder contar o *timing* da tragédia corretamente.

Fazer isso tudo de uma sentada só na `main()` é possível? Tecnicamente sim, mas a lógica seria tão complicada que é muito pouco provável de você acertá-la de primeira (ou de décima). Separando em funções fica muito mais fácil raciocinar sobre cada peça separadamente (aqui, o comportamento de cada ator em separado).

Comment: Wtrmute eu consegui resolver mudando as condiçoes, ele cria o segundo filho, mas seu codigo esta bem mais enchuto que o meu. Agora continuando a problematica. eu preciso criar o neto 1 do filho 1 e o neto 2 do filho 2.  - "Depois de 15 segundos após suas respectivas criações. Os processos Filho1, Filho2,

Neto1 e Neto2 também ficam executando indefinidamente."

Comment: Aí nesse caso, a criação do neto vai na `proc_filho()`, da mesma forma que o pai criou os filhos. Aí eu recomendaria a criação de uma `proc_neto()` que não gera outros bisnetos para rodar os netos (a não ser que você vá precisar gerar bisnetos), ou algo semelhante. Dividir para conquistar.

Comment: Show parceiro, deu certo a criaçao dos netos tbm. Continuando e por fim a problematica. No instante 50 segundos, Filho1 mata Pai.

- No instante 55 segundos, Filho1 mata seu filho e se suicida dois segundos depois

disto.

- No instante 60 segundos, Neto2 mata seu pai e se suicida três segundos depois,

terminando com a saga da família. (fim de novela).

Comment: Ok, neste caso você vai querer guardar os valores de retorno de `fork()` no caso dos filhos para saber o pid dos netos (para filho1 poder matar seu próprio filho). O pid do pai pode ser passado para os filhos como parâmetro ou o filho chamando `getppid()`. Então, "matar" é `kill(pid, SIGKILL)` e "suicidar-se" é ou `kill(getpid(), SIGKILL)` ou `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`. Lembre-se de incluir `<signal.h>`. Aliás, deixa eu atualizar a resposta com essas duas fases novas.

Comment: Muito bem explicado Wtrmute, ajudou mto mesmo, seu codigo limpo e objetivo e suas explicaçoes faceis de entender. Obgdo

Comment: Wtrmute tu testou teu codigo ai? eu rodei ele e apresentou uns bugs em relaçao a funçao do filho foi. Corrigi e rodei, mas ele entrou num laço infinito que gera sempre mais filhos ate topar a memoria a ponto de travar o pc.

Comment: Confesso que não; o erro é que na `proc_filho1()` e `proc_filho2()` eu escrevi `if (num_segundos == 15 & ! fork())`, com só um `&`. Como este é o operador bit-a-bit, ele não faz _shortcut evaluation_ como o `&&` faz e o `fork()` é chamado sempre.  Corrigindo.

Comment: @Wtrmute , usei essa sua resposta como exemplo de IPC de envio de sinais [nesta resposta sobre IPC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/214199/64969)

Comment: @Wtrmute pra mostrar a arvore de processos no ínicio da execução, no momento em que todos os processos estão criados e no momento final do programa, usando o comando (pstree -s <pid>). Uso o system("pstree -s pidPai"); porem ele retorno Nome de usuário inexistente: pidPai

Comment: @CarlosDiego: `system()` não faz interpolação de variáveis; tem [uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/194495/teria-como-adicionar-um-par%C3%A2metro-em-systemcolor-var-na-linguagem-c) do SOpt falando exatamente sobre isso.

Answer (score 1):

Que tal uma função genérica capaz de resolver o problema:

```
void fork_children( int count, int delay )
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    pid_t pid = 0;

    for ( i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        sleep(delay);

        pid = fork();

        if( pid == 0 )
        {
            debug( "Processo filho iniciado.");

            for( j = 0; j < 20; j++ )
            {
                debug( "Processo filho trabalhando..." );
                sleep(1);
            }

            break;
        }
        else if( pid == -1 )
        {
            std::cerr << "Erro no fork()!" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Programa exemplo (testado):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

#include <unistd.h>


#define CHILDREN_COUNT (2)
#define FORK_DELAY     (10)


void debug( const char * msg )
{
    char timestamp[32] = {0};
    time_t timer;
    struct tm* info;

    time(&timer);
    info = localtime(&timer);

    strftime( timestamp, sizeof(timestamp), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", info );

    std::cout << "[" << timestamp << "]-[PID " << getpid() << "]: " << msg << std::endl;
}


void fork_children( int count, int delay )
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    pid_t pid = 0;

    for ( i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        sleep(delay);

        pid = fork();

        if( pid == 0 )
        {
            debug( "Processo filho iniciado.");

            for( j = 0; j < 20; j++ )
            {
                debug( "Processo filho trabalhando..." );
                sleep(1);
            }

            break;
        }
        else if( pid == -1 )
        {
            std::cerr << "Erro no fork()!" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}


int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    debug( "Processo pai iniciado.");

    fork_children( CHILDREN_COUNT, FORK_DELAY );

    debug("Processo finalizado.");

    return 0;
}

/* fim-de-arquivo */
```

Saída:

```
$ ./novela
[2017-06-22 15:42:51]-[PID 25321]: Processo pai iniciado.
[2017-06-22 15:43:01]-[PID 25323]: Processo filho iniciado.
[2017-06-22 15:43:01]-[PID 25323]: Processo filho trabalhando...
[2017-06-22 15:43:02]-[PID 25323]: Processo filho trabalhando...
[2017-06-22 15:43:03]-[PID 25323]: Processo filho trabalhando...
[2017-06-22 15:43:04]-[PID 25323]: Processo filho trabalhando...
[2017-06-22 15:43:05]-[PID 25323]: Processo filho trabalhando...
[2017-06-22 15:43:06]-[PID 25323]: Processo filho trabalhando...
[2017-06-22 15:43:07]-[PID 25323]: Processo filho trabalhando...
[2017-06-22 15:43:08]-[PID 25323]: Processo filho trabalhando...
[2017-06-22 15:43:09]-[PID 25323]: Processo filho trabalhando...
[2017-06-22 15:43:10]-[PID 25323]: Processo filho trabalhando...
[2017-06-22 15:43:11]-[PID 25321]: Processo finalizado.
[2017-06-22 15:43:11]-[PID 25324]: Processo filho iniciado.
[2017-06-22 15:43:11]-[PID 25324]: Processo filho trabalhando...
[2017-06-22 15:43:11]-[PID 25323]: Processo filho trabalhando...
[2017-06-22 15:43:12]-[PID 25324]: Processo filho trabalhando...
[2017-06-22 15:43:12]-[PID 25323]: Processo filho trabalhando...
[2017-06-22 15:43:13]-[PID 25324]: Processo filho trabalhando...
[2017-06-22 15:43:13]-[PID 25323]: Processo filho trabalhando...
[2017-06-22 15:43:14]-[PID 25324]: Processo filho trabalhando...
[2017-06-22 15:43:14]-[PID 25323]: Processo filho trabalhando...
[2017-06-22 15:43:15]-[PID 25324]: Processo filho trabalhando...
[2017-06-22 15:43:15]-[PID 25323]: Processo filho trabalhando...
[2017-06-22 15:43:16]-[PID 25324]: Processo filho trabalhando...
[2017-06-22 15:43:16]-[PID 25323]: Processo filho trabalhando...
[2017-06-22 15:43:17]-[PID 25324]: Processo filho trabalhando...
[2017-06-22 15:43:17]-[PID 25323]: Processo filho trabalhando...
[2017-06-22 15:43:18]-[PID 25324]: Processo filho trabalhando...
[2017-06-22 15:43:18]-[PID 25323]: Processo filho trabalhando...
[2017-06-22 15:43:19]-[PID 25324]: Processo filho trabalhando...
[2017-06-22 15:43:19]-[PID 25323]: Processo filho trabalhando...
[2017-06-22 15:43:20]-[PID 25324]: Processo filho trabalhando...
[2017-06-22 15:43:20]-[PID 25323]: Processo filho trabalhando...
[2017-06-22 15:43:21]-[PID 25324]: Processo filho trabalhando...
[2017-06-22 15:43:21]-[PID 25323]: Processo finalizado.
[2017-06-22 15:43:22]-[PID 25324]: Processo filho trabalhando...
[2017-06-22 15:43:23]-[PID 25324]: Processo filho trabalhando...
[2017-06-22 15:43:24]-[PID 25324]: Processo filho trabalhando...
[2017-06-22 15:43:25]-[PID 25324]: Processo filho trabalhando...
[2017-06-22 15:43:26]-[PID 25324]: Processo filho trabalhando...
[2017-06-22 15:43:27]-[PID 25324]: Processo filho trabalhando...
[2017-06-22 15:43:28]-[PID 25324]: Processo filho trabalhando...
[2017-06-22 15:43:29]-[PID 25324]: Processo filho trabalhando...
[2017-06-22 15:43:30]-[PID 25324]: Processo filho trabalhando...
[2017-06-22 15:43:31]-[PID 25324]: Processo finalizado.
```